# HTML swf container resize

Tags: html, flash

I have a kinda simple flash file. Just one layer. For the first 50 frames I just have an img file which has 300px height. 
At 51 frame i load another image with the same width but with 150px height.

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>masterhead</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="980" height="235" id="masterhead" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="masterhead.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="masterhead.swf" width="980" height="235">
                    <param name="movie" value="eradio_masterhead.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
        <div>
        <br> just some text </br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem is that swf container doesn't resize at the frame 51.

How I ccan do that;

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Simply* ** Flash Cant**

The SWF file is a container pre compiled file, It will not resize as the properties of the file are already declared when you compiled it and in your parameters tags.

Html divs with Css will also not resize the SWF  as the page is separate and has no interactivity with the flash content already displayed.

Im not too sure if this would be possible with javascript during runtime, but that is another question....